# Gradient navigation bar width

Tags: html, css, navigation, gradient

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to go to the end of my page, i'm having trouble.
My navigation bar is gradient, and i've tried a few things to make it go from the very left side of the page to the very end of the right side, could i have some help please?
CSS:

```
.nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}


    .nav li {
float:left;
}

    .nav a:link, a:visited {
display:block;
width: %100;
font-weight:bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color:#363636;
background-image:url('../images/nav.png');
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#363636),to(#0A0A0A));
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#363636,#0A0A0A);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#363636,#0A0A0A);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#363636,#0A0A0A);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#363636,#0A0A0A);
background:linear-gradient(top,#363636,#0A0A0A);
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
text-decoration:none;
}

    .nav a:hover, a:active {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color:#0A0A0A;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#363636),to(#363636));
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#0A0A0A,#363636);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#0A0A0A,#363636);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#0A0A0A,#363636);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#0A0A0A,#363636);
background:linear-gradient(top,#0A0A0A,#363636);
}
```

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle of the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `Width` in the question's title... from the top of my head after looking at your code, try changing:

```
width: %100;
```

to

```
width: 100%;
```